# How to insert a found letter in the replacement string using preg replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace a string written bellow

```
AND ( (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%A%')
AND  (mt1.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%\"s2member\\_level2\"%') )
```

to

```
AND ( (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE 'A%')
AND  (mt1.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%\"s2member\\_level2\"%') )
```

In the above scring what I want to achieve is to replace `%[a-zA-Z]%` to `[a-zA-Z]%`

Comment: So what have you tried, is there anything you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the letter and insert in the replacement string again.

```
%([a-zA-Z])%
```

this will capture the letter because of the brackets around.

And replace with

```
$1%
```

`$1` is the content of that capturing group

in php it looks then something like

```
$SourceString = preg_replace('/%([a-zA-Z])%/', '$1%', $SourceString);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$string = str_replace("%A%", "%A", $string);`

Comment: What i want is replace "%[a-zA-Z]%" to "[a-zA-Z]%"

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure but you can try this .

```
$find ="/%A%/"; 
$replace ="A%"; 

echo preg_replace ($find, $replace, "AND ( (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%A%')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
$data = "AND ( (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%A%')
AND  (mt1.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%\"s2member\\_level2\"%') )";

$data = str_replace("%A%", "A%", $data);
```

Hope this helps